# Can't access website and Admin after Magento upgrade

Tags: magento2

I am running Magento in subfolder

www.mysite.com/magento

I just updated Magento to 2.2.3 using ssh,  everything was successful but now I am unable to access the website, or the Magento admin, I am having "Page not found" error from my root website "www.mysite.com"

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

The issue was with index.php permission

I changed it from 664 to 644.